# VBA "Query too complex" error using rs.UpdateBatch (MS SQL)

Tags: vba, excel

Getting the "Query too complex" VBA error when trying to run the below code and can't quite seem to figure out why?

```
Public Sub Update9MonthsDB(ByVal colSelection As Collection)

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

Call Open_Conn(strDb)

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.ActiveConnection = CON
rs.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
rs.Open ("Select * From [PortfolioDB$]")

For Each Item In colSelection

    strSQL = "Grid_Ref='" & Item & "'"

    rs.Find strSQL
    Debug.Print rs!Grid_Ref
    rs("MonthCheck9") = "1"
    Debug.Print rs!MonthCheck9

Next Item

rs.UpdateBatch
rs.Close

Call Close_Conn

End Sub
```

My connection string is used elsewhere in the code and is working fine for normal update/select etc statements. My debug prints show that the collection is not empty and returns the correct value with the other debug value check. But as soon as it gets to rs.UpdateBatch, it crashes out to "Query too complex" error.

EDIT: Just to clarify sorry, this is updating an excel spreadsheet acting as a database (back end)

EDIT: Connection string below as requested in comments.

```
Sub Open_Conn(strDb As String)
On Error GoTo conError
    Debug.Print (Time() & " - Connecting to: " & strDb)
    Set CON = New ADODB.Connection
    CON.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    CON.Open "Data Source=" & strDb & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=Yes"""
    Debug.Print (Time() & " - Connected")
    Exit Sub
conError:
    logevents ("There was an error processing the connection: " & strSQL & _        
    vbNewLine & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & Error(Err))
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line returns the error?  Can you run the query directly in your RDBMS?

Comment: The line it errors out on is `rs.UpdateBatch` it updates another spreadsheet I'm using as a backend. My employer dislikes Access Databases but requires something that can do a similar job so not sure how I would test it directly?

Comment: Try calling the [Update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676529(v=vs.85).aspx) method instead.  You'll need to do with within the loop before moving onto the next item.  [UpdateBatch can struggle](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FIQnCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA164&lpg=PA164&dq=Query+too+complex+UpdateBatch&source=bl&ots=FjqSKiUWkc&sig=z4V3DppeyzpfefZVT5VEeN6NTvU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjipu6GzpXKAhWBSXIKHTDoCW0Q6AEISDAG#v=onepage&q=Query%20too%20complex%20UpdateBatch&f=false) with certain data sources, large volumes, and datasets without a primary key.

Comment: Your employer dislikes Access but is OK with using Excel as a Database?

Comment: @TimWilliams correct

Comment: @destination-data Thanks for the suggestion, I tried as you said and I get no error now, but the database does not seem to actually update. I added this `rs.Update` within the loop as well as `Debug.Print rs!MonthCheck9` (for checking) and deleted `rs.UpdateBatch` the debug check returns "1" (correctly), but my actual file does not update. I tested in a simple sql update query to check field names etc and it worked fine.

Comment: What file type are you using? Can you also include the connection string?

Comment: @destination-data File type is an .xlsx. I've added connection string as requested. Though I have not manipulated an open rs like the above elsewhere in the code, all other select/insert/update queries are working correctly (just as an FYI)